# How to define a type which is union by 1 to 100?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to define a type to represent some error code, the value of which is a number between 1 and 100.

Now I have to do:

```
type ErrorCode = 1 | 2 | 3 | ...(many numbers) | 100
```

Is there any way to make it easier?

Comment: Nope. Manual all the way unfortunately.

Comment: Without [type arithmetic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15645) there's no good way to do this other than manually.  There are various hacks which can bog down or crash your compiler or make it give up... the one I came up with could only do `1 | 2 | ... | 22 | 23` before it gave up and became `any`.

Comment: There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) to support this, but it's not clear when or even if such a feature will make it into the language.  You could go there and give it a  or a comment describing your use case if you think it's new and different from the other ones there (there's a [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480#issuecomment-373984056) about HTTP status codes which is similar to this in scope).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, done